# from django.apps import apps No module named 'django.apps'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Hola soy nuevo usando django, estoy usando python 3.5 y django 1.9 pero luego de instalarlo e intentar crear mi primer proyecto me pone errores que no entiendo, es como si django no estuviese instalado pero si lo está?? Me pone:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rauli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.9.13-py3.5.egg\django\bin\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
  File "C:\Users\Rauli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.13-py3.5.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps
ImportError: No module named 'django.apps'
```

gracias de antemano.

Comment: Para verificar que esté instalado, puedes entrar siempre en la shell interactiva y escribir `import django` a ver si importa o no, la otra forma es en la consola escribir `pip freeze` y validar que django aparezca en la lista, para comprobar que se instaló correctamente

Comment: Estás usando un virtualenv o un entorno virtual de Conda? Estás siguiendo algún tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente código, en vez de:

> ```
> from django.core import management o 
> from django.app import app
> ```

pon:

```
from django import *
```

Siempre que uses una biblioteca te conviene importarla de ese modo porque así importas todos los módulos de esta de una sola vez y no tienes que, por cada módulo que necesites, importar la biblioteca de nuevo.